# Domain routes in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I want to point multiple subdomains and/or root domains to a single Play Framework 2.3 (Scala) application, for example apples.com, bananas.com or buy.bananas.com.

Depending on which domain the request comes in, I want to have different routes.

Ideally, it should work something like this:

```
GET    apples.com        @controllers.ApplesController.home
GET    bananas.com       @controllers.BananasController.home
GET    buy.bananas.com   @controllers.BananasController.buy
```

Is there any way to do this in Play Framework 2.3?

Comment: Things like this are better handled by http-servers... Not by frameworks. Still, you can achieve some of such functionality. For more details refer -> http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-multidomain-seed and https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-seed/blob/master/app/Global.scala

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh write an answer instead of comment, it's good point to upvote/accept

Comment: @biesior The scope of solution will not fit in an answer. Too many things to be understood and whole project needs to be created in a particular way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am working in java .Here is the way to do it in java maybe that could help

routes

```
GET    /             @controllers.ApplesController.index
GET    /apples       @controllers.ApplesController.home
GET    /bananas      @controllers.BananasController.home
GET    /buybananas   @controllers.BananasController.buy
```

controller

```
@With(CheckUrl.class)
public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Unable to resolve host."));
    }
```

CheckUrl.java

```
public class CheckUrl extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        String host = request().host();
        System.out.println("HOST IS "+host);

              if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("apples.com")) {

             return F.Promise.pure(redirect("/apples"));

        }else if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("bananas.com ")){

         return F.Promise.pure(redirect("/bananas"));

        }else if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("buy.bananas.com")){

         return F.Promise.pure(redirect("/buybananas"));
        }else{
          return delegate.call(ctx);
        }



}
```

I dont know if it the good way of doing it.I have tried it with `request().uri()` but not with `request().host()` and that worked for me.Maybe that could help.

Comment: This is a solution to my problem, thank you. Please make sure to also checkout the github link the other guy posted as a comment on my question. It's actually a nicer and cleaner way to do it in my opinion, so might be helpful to you as well.